# How can I enable debugging on LG G Stylo smart phone?

Tags: usb-debugging

I looked through all the options and did not see any thing for developeer settings.  I cannot figure out how to turn on the usb debugging for my LG G stylo phone, I imagin it is something pretty simple.

Comment: Did you [enable Developer options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16707217)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since android version 4.2.* and up the "Developer options" menu is hidden.

To enable Developer options you have to go to **About Phone** (or **About phone** > **Software info**) and tap **Build number** 7 times

Now you should have Developer options in the options menu as usually

Comment: Hi.I could not find a build number. when I clicked on About Phone, I got Phone Name, Update center, Network, Status, Battery, Hardawre info, Software info and legal info, no About phone?

Comment: Build number also could be inside Software Info :) Check if that works!

Answer (score 0):

yes build number was inside software info. Click it 7 times and return to settings menu and now developers options is listed above About Phone in the settings list.